# What is the cheapest .se domain registrar?

Tags: domains

I'm looking to register a .se domain but I can only find registrars that charge ~$50 and I was wondering if there's anything cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/search.aspx?ci=8990) currently lists .se domains at $29.99. Switch to the "International Pricing" tab, then open the "Europe" section in the table.